# How to have a MouseMove event fire only if the mouse is hovered over an element for at least a specific amount of time?

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent

I want to display a `JFrame` when a user move the mouse pointer inside over a certain area of a `JPanel` with a little delay. I show the `JFrame` by attaching a `MouseAdapter` to the `JPanel` and overriding the `MouseMove` method.

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    Point p= e.getLocationOnScreen();
    //check if Point p is within the boundaries of a rectangle.          
    //show a JFrame
  }                
});
```

To obtain the delay I think that I should use something like a `Thread` by using `sleep`, with the condition that it must be interrupted if the mouse is moved out of the boundaries, but I'm not sure that this is the best approach.
Currently, I only see on SO questions related to JavaScript. What's the best way to do it in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a good solution is by using `java.util.Timer`.

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
 private int delay = 1000;//1 second
 private Timer timer = null;
 private int startTime =0;

  @Override
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    Point p= e.getLocationOnScreen();
    boolean pointInArea=false;
    //check if Point p is within the boundaries of a rectangle.          
    if(pointInArea){
        //A JFrame is queued to be shown
        if(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime>delay){
          //A JFrame has been already shown, then show a new one
          startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          timer = new Timer();                    
          timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
              @Override
              public void run() {
                //LAUNCH JFrame
              }

          }, delay);                     
        }
     }
     else (!pointInArea && timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;                        
     }
  }                
});
```

Comment: this has some drawbacks.. if the mouse pointer is hovering inside the object then it will cancel the timer.

Comment: good work.. But i would suggest to use the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` events. Because, everytime the mouse is moved, the move event is checked if it had entered a specific region. But if you use the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` the continuous resource consuming check will not happen.

Comment: But both work if you handle the boundaries of a `JComponent`. I'm interested in a specific area inside a `JPanel`, not in the whole component area.

Comment: If that is the case, your answer is the way to go, as you cannot trigger an event for hovering over a specific co-ordinate of a JPanel except with the use of the `mouseMoved` event. There are also other problems if you use the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited`events. For instance, an entry into a component inside the JPanel will be treated as an exit from the Jpanel. You have to write more code to handle those situations. So as i said before, yours is the way to go.. :) +1 for that..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`mouseEntered`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html#mouseEntered%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) and [`mouseExited`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html#mouseExited%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) events from the [`MouseAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) class.

You can set a timer on the `mouseEntered` method and check if the time spent on the object is `>=` the designated time in the `mouseExited` method and if so perform the action.

For the scenario of mouse left at the same point, you can use the [**`Timer`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) with a delay of how many ever seconds you want and setup a handler at `mouseExited` to stop the timer if the pointer is exited before the designated time.

Comment: And what about the case the mouse is left on the same point without moving?

Comment: Yeah, I just provided an answer with a Timer, not the swing one, but the util one.

Comment: @mat_boy check my comment on your answer. Your answer is good but you have to check if the pointer is hovering inside your component then it should not cancel the timer as the criteria is to show your jframe if the pointer is within your component for a designated time.